# Subtract set of lines from a line

Tags: c#, 2d

I have lsit of lines. In the list lines can be overlapped. Now I want to subtract these lines to a line to get a set of new lines.

In other words I need to `split` the line.

How can I achieve this in C#

Ex:

```
  List<Line> lines = new List<Line>();
    line = new Line();

    SubtractLine (Line, Lines);
```

Comment: show us how far did you do. and please read [Ask].

Comment: Code removed, I will add new code shortly

Comment: I can't see anywhere where lines are mentioned in that code.  It's not really much help!

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use

```
lines.remove (line);
```